# DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().GetDateTimeFormats() returns an array with different number of elements on Windows 7 and Windows 10

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime, datetime-format, cultureinfo

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().GetDateTimeFormats()
```

When I run the above C# code on Windows 7, it returns an array with 133 elements, however, when the same code is executed on Windows 10, it returns only 100 elements. Is there a culture-independent way to access the elements so that a particular date format is always present at a fixed index of the array.

Is there any patch or hotfix that I can apply to Windows 10, so that it returns 133 elements, just like Windows 7.

Comment: That seems like an XY-Problem. What are you trying to *do* that would require a fixed index into a dynamic sequence?

Comment: Those formats _depends_ on operating system version and/or .net framework version. There is _no_ patch or hotfix to equalize them on different environments. Also MSDN page states: `Because this method uses culture-sensitive data, you should not assume that multiple calls to the method will return identical data. The data returned by this method can change if the current culture changes, the user overrides individual cultural settings, or an update occurs to the system's cultural data.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. This is specifically mentioned in the documentation:

> Because this method uses culture-sensitive data, you should not assume that multiple calls to the method will return identical data. The data returned by this method can change if the current culture changes, the user overrides individual cultural settings, or an update occurs to the system's cultural data.

You can use this method's overload to pass a `IFormatProvider` (for example `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`) but still the above warning applies. This is not a list that you should keep an index too for whatever reason. It's subject to change.